# how does "[" modify aggregate (R)

Tags: r, aggregate

I'm working through Analzying Baseball data with R, and for one line of code they want to calculate the number of runs each half-inning begins with and they use line of code:

```
RUNS.SCORED.START = aggregate(data2011$RUNS,
                          list(HALF.INNING=data2011$HALF.INNING), "[", 1)
```

So I was wondering what the "[", 1) portion at the end does - it's different than sum, because when I replace that section with "sum" the numbers change completely.

Comment: `[` can be used as a function. It's equivalent to `df[1]` for each group in your `aggregate` code

Comment: As useR says, run this: `x <- 1:5; '['(x,2)`.

Comment: So same as `aggregate(data2011$RUNS,
                          list(HALF.INNING=data2011$HALF.INNING), function(x) x[1])`

Comment: Also, the formula interface is easy: `aggregate(RUNS ~ HALF.INNING, data = data2011, "[", 1)`.